# Significato di "andare nell'anima" in questo contesto

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Il barone rampante*, di Italo Calvino, ho letto:

> La sua levata aveva disorientato segugi e cacciatori. Sul sentiero correva un vecchio con un greve archibugio. –Ehi,– gli fece Cosimo, – quel bassotto è vostro? 
>         – Ti **andasse nell'anima** a te e a tutti i tuoi parenti! – gridò il vecchio che doveva aver le sue lune. – Ti sembriamo tipi da cacciare coi bassotti?

Potreste spiegarmi il significato dell'espressione "andare nell'anima" in questo passaggio? Nel [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/anima/) ho trovato

> *andare, arrivare all’a.*, toccare profondamente

ma non mi sembra che questo abbia molto senso nel brano sopra citato.

Comment: Lo considererei una sorta di eufemismo per mandare a quel paese (altro eufemismo) l'interlocutore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

È un’imprecazione dovuta al fatto che il vecchio è arrabbiato (sembrava avesse le sue lune) per il fatto che gli viene chiesto se caccia con i bassotti, cosa che viene considerata in qualche modo negativa in quanto probabilmente metteva in dubbio la sua esperienza come cacciatore.

A Roma probabilmente avrebbero detto “all’anima de li mortacci tua”.